# database and jquery timepicker

Tags: jquery, database, timepicker

I use timepicker and the jquery permit to select the hour and minute interval we want. I would like to have different minute interval depends on the data in my database. For example if the database number is 5 I want to have

```
   minutes: {
      starts: 0, // first displayed minute
      ends: 55,  // last displayed minute
     interval: 5 // interval of displayed minutes
   },
```

and if it's 15 I would like to have

```
   minutes: {
      starts: 0, // first displayed minute
      ends: 45,  // last displayed minute
     interval: 15 // interval of displayed minutes
   },
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to do this since I don't know a lot about jquery. After I'm using php.

does anyone have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply output an js variable with php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var interval_from_database = <?php echo($interval); ?>;
</script>
```

where $interval is your php variable with the interval value you got from the database.
And then you can just do it like this:

```
minutes: {
  starts: 0, // first displayed minute
  ends: 45,  // last displayed minute
 interval: interval_from_database // interval of displayed minutes
},
```

Comment: thanks I try it. if the interval is 10, instead of put 00, 10, 20... it will put 00, 010 and nothing else do i need to change something else?

Comment: Please have a look at the source code of your php page in your browser. Which value is assigned to the js variable `interval_from_database`?

Comment: the value assigned is: var interval_from_database = '10';

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake, please remove `'` in the js variable code: `var interval_from_database = <?php echo($interval); ?>;` It must not be a string. Answer edited. Does it work now?